# Python: how to slice a dictionary based on the values of its keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, slice, hashable

Say I have a dictionary built like this:

`d={0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 10:4, 11:5, 12:6, 100:7, 101:8, 102:9, 200:10, 201:11, 202:12}`

and I want to create a subdictionary `d1` by slicing `d` in such a way that `d1` contains the following keys: `0, 1, 2, 100, 101, 102`. The final output should be:

`d1={0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 100:7, 101:8, 102:9}`

**Is there an efficient Pythonic way of doing this, given that my real dictionary contains over 2,000,000 items?**

I think this question applies to all cases where keys are integers, when the slicing needs to follow certain *inequality rules*, and when the final result needs to be a bunch of slices put together in the same dictionary.

Comment: Where do those rules come from? What should happen if those keys don't have values? Have you considered a dictionary comprehension `{k: d[k] for k in [0, 1, ...]}`?

Comment: In my case all keys have values.

Comment: You can't really "slice" a dictionary, since it's a mutable mapping and not a sequence.  I think dict comprehension is your best bet.

Comment: Slicing a dictionary isn't inherently impossible; Python just doesn't provide syntax for doing it like, say, Perl does (although in Perl, you just get back the corresponding values, not a subset of the hash).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use dictionary comprehension with:

```
d = {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 10:4, 11:5, 12:6, 100:7, 101:8, 102:9, 200:10, 201:11, 202:12}
keys = (0, 1, 2, 100, 101, 102)
d1 = {k: d[k] for k in keys}
```

In python 2.7 you can also compute keys with (in python 3.x replace `it.ifilter(...)` by `filter(...)`):

```
import itertools as it

d = {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 10:4, 11:5, 12:6, 100:7, 101:8, 102:9, 200:10, 201:11, 202:12}
d1 = {k: d[k] for k in it.ifilter(lambda x: 1 < x <= 11, d.keys())}
```

Comment: Well, I should have pointed this out in the first place. While it is true that I know what the needed keys, they are too many to be put explicitly in a tuple. Is there a way to construct the tuple using inequality rules?

Comment: @CF84: What is you definition of the inequality rule? Please share the complete info, we can not read your mind :)

Comment: One definition could be to "draft" all values which keys are greater than and smaller than a certain value `x`. Example: `06010001 < x <= 06012000`.

Comment: see my updated answer. With python 3.x you  just have to replace it.filter(...) by filter(...)

Answer (score 3):

One succinct way of creating the sub-dictionary is to use `operator.itemgetter`. This function takes multiple arguments and returns a new function to return a tuple containing the corresponding elements of a given iterable.

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig

k = [0, 1, 2, 100, 101, 102]
# ig(0,1,2,100,101,102) == lambda d : (d[0], d[1], d[2], d[100], d[101], d[102])
d1 = dict(zip(k, ig(*k)(d)))
```